# mysql query for show all friendnames in home page?

Tags: php

when a user will log in his profile then he will c all of his friends in his home page,I have 2 tables,no1:-table name fsb_profile containing profile_id,profile_name,etc table no2:- fsb_friendlist containing friendlist_memberid,friendlist_friendid.now i want to show the friend details in home page,

**my code is:-**

```
$id=$_SESSION["_ID"];
$query = "select * from fsb_profile " .
         "where fsb_profile.profile_id=(" .
             "select fsb_friendlist.friendlist_friendid " .
             "from fsb_friendlist " .
             "where friendlist_memberid=" . $id . ")";

if( $sql = mysql_query($query) ) {
    while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "hai";
        echo $t["profile_name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "Something went horribly wrong.\n";
}
```

**error:-**Something went horribly wrong.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work.

Comment: This is a rewrite of your earlier question where people were trying to help you solve the problem: [php query is not running??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210559/php-query-is-not-running).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
if( $sql = mysql_query($query) ) {
    while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "hai";
        echo $t["profile_name"];
    }
} else {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

To see what went horribly wrong so that we could provide you with better possible solution.

Also make sure that you have put `session_start()` on top of your script.

Comment: i have checked the session_start() its there,now the error became
Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @mriganka3: You do not seem to have tried my code to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM fsb_profile
    WHERE fsb_profile.profile_id IN (
        SELECT fsb_friendlist.friendlist_friendid
        FROM fsb_friendlist
        WHERE friendlist_memberid = $id
        );
```

i.e. replace `fsb_profile.profile_id=(` with `fsb_profile.profile_id IN (`

**Edit**:

I didn't pay attention to the actual query, I only tried to correct the error you are getting. The correct query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM fsb_profile
    WHERE fsb_profile.profile_id IN (
        SELECT friendlist_memberid
        FROM fsb_friendlist
        WHERE friendlist_friendid = $id
        );
```

Comment: it is showing the profile_name of the $id,but i want to show the name of the friends

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query

`SELECT * FROM fsb_profile WHERE fsb_profile.profile_id IN((SELECT GROUP_CONCAT() FROM fsb_friendlist WHERE friendlist_memberid=$id ))`